# is ConnectionInfo class in ehters 5.x?

Tags: ethers.js

Here is the doc about provider in ethers 5.x document:

```
new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider( [ urlOrConnectionInfo [ , networkish ] ] )

Connect to a JSON-RPC HTTP API using the URL or ConnectionInfo urlOrConnectionInfo connected to the networkish network.

If urlOrConnectionInfo is not specified, the default (i.e. http://localhost:8545) is used and if no network is specified, it will be determined automatically by querying the node using eth_chaindId and falling back on eth_networkId.
```

How to create `urlOrConnectionInfo` of `ConnectionInfo` type? The `ConnectionInfo` seems to be a class but I am having hard time to find information such as `import` and `initialization` about it.

Comment: urlOrConnectionInfo is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the `json-rpc-provider.ts` file you can find the constructor declaration

```
export class JsonRpcProvider extends BaseProvider {
  ...
  constructor(url?: ConnectionInfo | string, network?: Networkish) {
  ...
```

`url` can be a `string` or a [ConnectionInfo](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/web/#ConnectionInfo).

`ConnectionInfo` is an object with properties:

```
// Exported Types
export type ConnectionInfo = {
    url: string,
    headers?: { [key: string]: string | number }

    user?: string,
    password?: string,

    allowInsecureAuthentication?: boolean,
    allowGzip?: boolean,

    throttleLimit?: number,
    throttleSlotInterval?: number;
    throttleCallback?: (attempt: number, url: string) => Promise<boolean>,

    timeout?: number,
};
```